# Email confirmation periods

Tags: support, email-notification, responses

I think it's wrong that email confirmation comes hours later after a response has been posted.

Can't the CRON task be set to run quicker?

Comment: That's a bit of an assumption by yourself. Email is **not** instantaneous and can be delayed anywhere between where it was sent and where it arrives. As far as I know, we send confirmation emails as soon as we generate them - these are not on a schedule. Though it would be clearer if you explained exactly **what** confirmation email you are talking about.

Comment: You are right. I have assumed perhaps incorrectly. What prompted my comment is that I got successive emails about responses to my questions 4-5 hours after the responses were posted

Comment: OK. Why would we send emails about responses immediately? There is no immediacy here for most people (and if there is, F5 exists). I thought you meant some other "confirmation" email (getting an email that your question got answers is not confirming anything), so I didn't quite get what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notifications about answers to your questions **are not sent immediately**.

When asking a question, if you want to be notified by email about answers, there is a UI for that:

> [image: email about new responses - schedules are every 3 hours, daily or weekly]

You will note that the **minimum** schedule is every 3 hours, so it is fair to expect that notification about getting answers are not immediate.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I will look into that